# Finding the ith smallest key greater than k in an AVL tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree and want to implement a function that returns the ith smallest key greater than input k. Does this require storing the sizes of the subtrees at each node? If anyone could give a general outline of the idea, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to store the sizes of the subtrees on each node?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply search for `Key+1` if it exists then you get the value else you have to keep track of last key visited in the search as that will be your answer. The search routine in avl is same as that in BST.

Comment: Isn't the question asking about `i`-th value greater than `k`, not the first one?

Comment: @Gassa yes i think i missed that because it is not highlighted that. Then i think he also need size of subtree as an attribute to determine that in O(logN)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to store the size of the subtree on each node you can simply search for the value *k* and, on your way back from the recursion, for every left child you took, you can add the size of the right child plus one for the parent node. If at any point this summation is greater than *i* you have to go into the right child and subtract the right child plus one (again for node itself) and move to the left child. If subtracting the entire right child is too much then you just move to the right child recursively. This takes O(lg n).

On the other hand, if you are not allowed to store the size of the subtree on each node, you have to search for the position where the value *k* should be, and from there on make an *in-order* traversal of the tree counting each visited node. Since *in-order* visits left-node-right, in your way back from the search you will count only values greater than *k* in increasing order. This method takes O(lg n + i).